# Multiplexer with 5v select and 9v or more routing

Tags: multiplexer

I need to route a 9v signal using a 5v or 3.3v microcontroller. Does anybody know of a multiplexer that supports this, or a circuit it could put in between the microcontroller and the multiplexer to make this happen. The multiplexers i have tried (TI cd4097b) will only route the signal up to the voltage of the select pins and not higher.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analog devices make some parts that can switch larger signal ranges than the logic levels of their control signals. I'm using the ADG1404 for such an application in one of my current designs.

---

> When looking at the datasheet can you point out what tells you that a device is capable of that. Knowing what to look for would be really helpful when picking the components i need for this project.

In the case of the 1404 it's in the headline features

- Fully specified at +12 V, ±15 V, and ±5 V
- No VL supply required
- 3 V logic-compatible inputs

In my experiance at least with Analog Devices most of their parts with digital control inputs (switches, muxes, instrumentation amps, digipots etc) tend to have logic inputs with thresholds that make sense for modern logic even while the analog ranges are much wider. It is also common to have seperate ground and negative supply pins to allow the logic to be referenced to ground while the analog signals passing through are bipolar.

The 4000 series is extremely old so it's not so surprising that it doesn't have modern conviniances.

Comment: When looking at the datasheet can you point out what tells you that a device is capable of that. Knowing what to look for would be really helpful when picking the components i need for this project.

Comment: I've tried to expand but i'm not a massive expert. I'm mostly a digital guy who sometimes ends up doing some analog stuff as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use level shifters between your micro and the ABCD select pins.

You could use an open-collector transistor with pull-up resistor or a Darlington driver chip such as [ULN2803A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question. I did a quick search, but my intuition tells me **most (if not all) ICs are going to need to be supplied** *(at the VCC pin)* **with 9V in order to pass through a 9V signal**.

*In other words*, the voltage that the IC can pass through shouldn't depend on the voltage of the select pins, but the supply voltage of the IC of the IC.

If your system can supply 9V to power the chip, then great.

After that, you'll need to boost your input signals **or use a level shifter** (3.3V or 5V --> 9V) to drive the inputs. It's possible that some chips might be able to accept those low voltages as valid input signals. You'll be able to find this information in a datasheet under the **Electrical Specifications**Electrical Specifications section. You will be looking for the V(IH) rating. V(IH) will give the lowest voltage that the chip will detect as a "HIGH" signal on the inputs.

Comment: Do you know of a 3.3V or 5V --> 9V level shifter?

Comment: A single transistor can do that @ianjorgensen, either inverting when using CE or non-inverting using CB. Search for "BJT level shifter".

Comment: Yes, you can create your own level shifter very easily. This document explains it here: http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10441.pdf. The document is written towards I2C, but the concept is the same. @jippie, would you say it's easier to do it with a MOSFET over a BJT?

Comment: Also, @ianjorgensen, most level shifters allow you to supply your own voltages to the levels that you want to shift between. You just need to find one that is tolerant for the voltage you're using. Try searching Mouser here: http://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Logic-ICs/Translation-Voltage-Levels/_/N-4s6ih?FS=True. I've filtered it down to Logic ICs -> Voltage Level Translation.

Comment: For 3V3 I would prefer BJT's because I don't have any MOSFETs in my personal parts drawer that comfortably switch at 3V3. Notice that threshold voltage is not necessarily the correct parameter to look at in this respect. @Anton